# Disable Bluetooth Full Volume Beep in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth

Since I switched to Ubuntu 22.04, I've found that changing the system sound volume while using a bluetooth speaker produces a nasty beep as the volume passes the "full" volume threshold. Is there a way to disable this highly irritating beep?! I'd prefer a solution that doesn't involve disabling all system sound alerts.